# Setting PATH with two different TexLive versions

Tags: 13.04, latex, paths

I have two different versions of TexLive: the Ubuntu binaries for TexLive 2012, which live in `usr/share`, and TexLive 2013 which lives in `usr/local`. As per instructions [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html), my PATH now looks like the following:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x68_64-linux:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

The PATH is set in both my .bashrc and .profile files by

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x68_64-linux:$PATH
export $PATH
```

Yet, whenever I run pdflatex or xelatex, it is taking the Ubuntu TexLive 2012 versions, while I need TexLive 2013. (specifically, running `xelatex my_example.tex` results in some errors like `` LaTeX Error: File `unicode-math.sty' not found. ``)

My TexLive 2013 does exist: `ls -l /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x68_64-linux` returns the [following](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5924736/).

To use TexLive 2013, I need to manually run something like: `/usr/loca/texlive/2013/bin/x68_64-linux/xelatex my_example.tex` (this does not return the unicode-math errors and generates the pdf nicely).

Also (tlmgr is not in Ubuntu distributions of TexLive):

```
tlgmr
No command 'tlmgr' found, did you mean:
Command 'rlmgr' from package 'qdbm-util' (universe)
Command 'vlmgr' from package 'qdbm-util' (universe)
tlmgr: command not found
```

But:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr
tlmgr: missing action; try --help if you need it.
```

How can I set my PATH correctly that it takes TexLive 2013 as default?

Comment: Do you need both versions because of backward compatibility reasons?  If not, I would recommend switching to texlive 2013 via a Ubuntu PPA rather than installing your own additional version and complicating your system further.

Comment: Since I was just dealing with [a very similar problem](http://askubuntu.com/a/435995/161463) successfully, my guess would be the executables are not really in your path. You may want to narrow down the problem be checking `which latex`. Do you for instance have proper read/write permissions for all binaries in `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x68_64-linux`?